# Magento2 - How to get payment status from Stripe

Tags: magento2, rest-api, stripe

I would like to know if there is a any way to get the payment status from Stripe based on Magento order id.

I have checked this doc, I got this [Search PaymentIntents](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/search?lang=curl) example to search payment. Once I have checked curl call and ran it, it wasn't working for me. Always it gave me an empty result. Any code example for Magento2?

[image]

Your help will be greatly appreciated. Thank You

Comment: Just to make sure the API is working and the account contains orders.  Have you tried to just query for the order_id to make sure it exists or all orders with status equal succeeded?

Comment: Yes I passed correct order status and order id. Once I passed only status, it was working. If I passed only order Id or order I’d with status, I didn’t get any error but received only empty result.